# Is "General Failure" the intended response after you put your computer to sleep while pinging something?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, sleep, ping

I'm curious as to what normally happens if you put your computer to sleep while you're pinging something.

I get a few lines of "General Failure" immediately after waking the computer up. I assumed the pinging would stop while the computer was asleep, only to immediately resume as soon as it woke up.

How is it still able to log that in the command prompt window while it's asleep?

Answer (score 1):

"General Failure" typically comes up when the interface data is being sent through is not working.   I posit you are seeing the result of pings which were sent when the computer was preparing to sleep and when it woke up but hand not yet restored the Interface.

A computer in sleep mode does not send out any traffic.